# Show only different symbols. Not entire line

Tags: diff

windows 10, dired+

when I compare two files I get this:

[image]

The different in this file are two words:

```
first 

second
```

But `diff` tool show me that is different ENTIRE line.
It's not very good.
Is it possible to show only exact different symbols?

smt like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You apparently used `dired-diff`.

Please just provide the recipe as part of your question. Don't throw a (very hard to read) screenshot at us.

The behavior of the command depends on your OS `diff` command. Use `M-x man diff` to see what switch possibilities there are and whether any of them help you get the behavior you want.

If so, then use `C-u dired-diff`. You'll be prompted for the switches to use.